# Append <img> to <tbody> with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an AJAX call, and on success, a HTML `<img>` element is appended to the `tbody`.

Here is the code:

```
for (var i = 0; i <= list.length - 1; i++) {
    var patientsList = ' <td class="point">' +
        (i+1) +
        '</td>' +
        '<td class="title"> ' +
        list[i].dateOfBirthday +
        '</td>' +
        '<td class="title"> ' +
        list[i].lastName +
        '</td>' +
        '<td class="title"> ' +
        list[i].firstName +
        '</td>' + '<td>' + '</td>'
        + '<td>' + '</td>'
        + '<td>' + '</td>'
        + '<td style="text-align:end;>' + ' <img src="~/images/doc 50.png" />'+ '</td>';

    $("#patients").append('<tr>' + patientsList + '</tr>');
};
```

The problem is, the image does not appear in the table.

The path is correct.

Why is it not appending?

Answer (score 0):

Path is not correct. Try `./` instead of `~/` .

Comment: Correct. It's ASP.NET project path

Answer (score 0):

Your image name contains whitespace: `doc 50.png`. Try to rename the file and replace the code with something like this:

```
<img src="./images/doc-50.png" />'
```

And if your `images` folder is at the same level as the file, which code you have provided, use `./`, not `~/`.

Comment: Correct. It's ASP.NET project path